# Angular decimal pipe rounding up as I type in resulting in wrong value

Tags: angular

I have used **decimal** pipe of Angular as given below:

```
<input pInputText type="number" [ngModel]="factor | number: '.2'" (ngModelChange)="factor=$event">
```

It is working when my page loads. I have set factor to 50 in **.ts** file and it is showing up as 50.00 on UI. However when I erase that value and trying to type in 77, it makes value as 7.00 as I enter first digit and second digit is going at last as 7.007. It is happening for all the values. I don't want it to behave that way. Am I doing anything wrong here?

StackBlitz for it is at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ke8dd9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those pipes do not work with inputs well because the value is changed as you type, I believe they are meant for static numbers formatting. You could consider updating the value on blur:

```
<input
  type="number"
  [ngModel]="factor | number: '.2'"
  [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
  (ngModelChange)="factor=$event">
```

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is because the pipe fires when the user first starts typing. This is because of the `ngModelChange` event which sets the `factor` value. If you want the number to be formatted I suggest using the `blur` event instead which will format the field once the user leaves the field.

```
<input pInputText type="number" [ngModel]="factor | number: '.2'" (blur)="factor=$event">
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-munrao)

Comment: If you are using Angular 5+ check out my answer :) Angular has built-in form hooks for when to update control value.

Comment: @pokrishka - very nice.